# How many cpu cores can a single java process make use of?

Tags: performance, memory-management, jvm

I'm running some performance tests to determine response times and ability to handle concurrency with various cpu / ram / os configurations. One interesting find I've run into, is that, it looks like a single jvm performs better with 4 cores than it does with 2 cores (no surprise there), but adding more cores beyond the 4th core does not result in any significant improvements. But then, adding another jvm instance with a load balancer (same hardware) resulted in a dramatic improvement.

It looks like an individual process is limited in the number of cores it can utilize, perhaps due to a limitation on the number of os threads a process can spawn at a time. This is a 64 bit environment.

Im using tomcat and tried changing the "maxThreads" attribute but that didn't make a difference for the amount of concurrency Im looking to handle.

Any other reason this could be explained?

Comment: "Depends on what is taking advantage of the currency and how"? (Or is there a more ingrained issue like only being able to spawn threads on 4 cores? Some affinity?)

Comment: Which JVM are you using?  It seems unlikely that there would be a limitation on the number of cores that may be utilised.

Comment: Maybe you're bound to something else but pure CPU, e.g. a database pool. Or the tomcat user sessions.

Comment: Im using Sun HotSpot 1.6.25, for the sake of testing I only have application logic, no i/o, db connections etc.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a Java application will try to schedule every active thread on a separate core.   This includes the GC threads.   If the application was not CPU-bound in the first place, then adding more cores would not make any difference as the threads are blocked by something.

For a web application, things get a little more complicated.  Increasing the size of the thread pool won't make any difference if there is something else that the threads are waiting on, like a database from a database connection pool, for example.   You need to look carefully at your load balancer and Tomcat configurations.   If those are not tuned properly it is very easy to have the behavior you describe.

I wouldn't worry too much about the JVM being limited in the number of threads it can have.   I routinely see over 600 threads in every JVM in our production system.   We use 8 core machines and the requests are short in duration, so most of these threads are in an I/O wait state.

Comment: "a Java application will try to schedule every active thread on a separate core"... JVMs don't schedule threads, the OS scheduler decides which threads get cpu time and on which cores they run.

Comment: True, i/o could be a bottleneck (though it isn't in my case). My experiment indicates that two java processes are able to use a piece of hardware more effectively than a single process on the same hardware. Im curious to know if that's to be expected and if its due to limitations placed by the os on how much clock a single process may be given..

Comment: @Matt True if you're using native threads (which you should be!).  Not necessarily if you're using green threads.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads